# Running a part of python code for sometime and then proceed to rest

Tags: python, timer

Is there any way to run a part of python code(once) for some time and then proceed to rest of the code.

```
 # time start 
 while #  there is time run the loop
   print("Hello World")

 # time end proceed to rest of code
 print("rest of the code being executed")
```

Comment: Yes, just use a comparison as part of the `while` statement. For example `while datetime.datetime.utcnow() < datetime.datetime.max:` but replace the comparators with whatever is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Why do you think you need multithreading for this? We need a bit more context or a simplified example that can be run. Do you want the other function to be executed for a finite time? Until it is over? A certain number of times? None of those seems cases for multithreading though.

Comment: I thought may be threading could be a solution in someway.